# Why does the hover for my JSDoc type definition unioning with null in VS Code not show null as part of the union?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have the following `LinkedList` class definition using JSDoc and `jsconfig.json` for type checking in VSCode. In it it should display the type of `value` and `next` as union types with undefined, however it does not, only showing their default type.

```js
class LinkedListNode {
  /**
   * @param {number | undefined} value
   * @param {LinkedListNode | undefined} next
   */
  constructor(value, next) {

    /** @type {number} */
    this.value = value ?? 0;

    /** @type {LinkedListNode | null} */
    this.next = next ?? null;
  }
}
```

Taking the following line as an example, thought it applies to all the unions.

```js
/** @type {LinkedListNode | null} */
this.next = next ?? null;
```

The hover message on `this.next` is currently, not showing correctly:

```
(property) LinkedListNode.next: LinkedListNode
```

What I wish to see:

```
(property) LinkedListNode.next: LinkedListNode | null
```

I have tried the following, none of which have worked:

```
/** @type {LinkedListNode | null} */
/** @type {?LinkedListNode} */
/** @type {(LinkedListNode|null)} */
```

Comment: could you interface be wrong? what if you put it to `* @param {LinkedListNode | null | undefined} next`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asker of this question already gave a sort of correct answer, which is that you can change this behaviour in a [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)'s compiler options using [the `strict` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict).

But they've missed two important things:

1. The `strict` property isn't directly the property of interest. The real config property of interest is [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks), which *defaults* to `true` if `strict` is set to `true`, and otherwise defaults to `false`.
2. jsconfig.json actually has implicit defaults that are configurable in VS Code settings- specifically, those that start with "`js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.`" (a bit of an obscure fact, though [there are traces/hints of its existence in relevant documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript)). The particular setting of interest here is `js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.strictNullChecks`, *which defaults to `true`*.

So if you piece that together with the problem description in the question, the first thing to check is that you haven't accidentally set the `js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.strictNullChecks` VS Code setting to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I had forgotten something important.

In my `jsconfig.json` I had forgotten to put in `"strict": true`. Which turns out to disables `nullish` unions in this case.

So after putting it in my `jsconfig.json`, and reloading VSCode it now displays the union correctly on the tooltip.